# Selenium - Making the invisible browser visible

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, captcha

I will register on a website and perform a few actions using Selenium.But there is an hcaptcha verification during the registration process.Is there a way to bypass or overcome the hcaptcha verification?(free) I couldn't find a way to bypass the hcaptcha verification, so I have decided to let the user handle this part.However, the browser starts in hidden mode (--headless). How can I make it visible when the hcaptcha appears and then hide it again after the hcaptcha is solved?

Comment: I don't think you can switch from headless to a regular window, but you could initialize the driver with a window, and then minimize it until it requires user interaction.

Comment: try just using the same profile, you should be able to close the non-headless window and open a new headless one that will be past the captcha